# Netty, how to mock ChannelFuture/ChannelPromise?

Tags: java, netty

I am using [Netty 4.0](http://netty.io/)  to create a distributed privacy preserving algorithm for my masters thesis. I do TDD and most of the time this works very well because of *Netty*'s modular API. One problem I get stuck on last week is I do not know how to test code that depends on `ChannelFutureListener`. So lets say I have following code in my application:

```
public ChannelFuture close() {
    if(channel == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Channel is null.");

    ChannelFuture f = channel.close();
    f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture chf) throws Exception {
            channel = null;
        }
    });

    return f;
}
```

Now I am trying to test this specific method with unit tests. For that to work, I need a way to mock out the `ChannelFuture` (ChannelPromise) to control the call of `operationComplete` method of the listener. I tried it with different approaches. Here is one example test case:

```
@Test
public void testConnectAfterClose() {
    Channel chMock = mock(Channel.class);
    ChannelPromise promise = new DefaultChannelPromise(chMock);

    when(chMock.close()).thenReturn(promise);
    node.connect(address);
    node.close();
    promise.setSuccess();
    node.connect(address);
}
```

This test results in a `NullPointerException` at `DefaultPromise.notifyListeners()`. Therefore my question is, how could I test code that depends on `ChannelFutureListener`s?

Comment: Down votes are very helpful without leaving a comment, Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Netty so I have no idea where it originates, but `DefaultPromise.notifyListeners()` looks like a static method invocation which may need to be stubbed as well. If you're using plain ol' Mockito you won't be able to mock static, private, etc methods. however you can do that with PowerMockito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out a way to solve my problem. It works if the mock of the channel (`chMock`) is replaced with a real channel, for example `EmbeddedChannel`. After that I use a `spy` for the channel instead of the mock.

Here is my current solution:

```
@Test
public void testConnectAfterClose() {
    Channel helper = new EmbeddedChannel(mock(ChannelHandler.class));
    chMock = spy(helper);

    when(chMock.close()).thenReturn(promise);
    node.connect(address);
    node.close();
    promise.setSuccess();
    node.connect(address);
}
```

@Morfic: Thank you for your comment. It was a nice hint for my current solution.

Comment: Worked for me also